# Does level adjustment count for Initiator Level in Tome of Battle (for maneuvers)?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, tome-of-battle

Say I want to build a half dragon half human crusader, with a total equivalent level of 5.

Has he 3 as Initiator Level or 1 ?

Level Adjustment = +3 divided by 2 = 1.5 
Starting Crusader as level 2 (total level = 5)

Thanks !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Stictly speaking, no.

> If you are a multiclass adept, and you learn a new maneuver by attaining a new level in a martial adept class, determine your initiator level by adding together your level in that class + 1/2 your **levels in all other classes**.

<sup>(*Tome of Battle* pg. 39, **emphasis** mine)</sup>

It specifies only levels in classes, so racial hit dice and level adjustment, officially, do not qualify.

However, since the entire ECL system is a nearly-unmitigated disaster and choosing a race with any LA at all is almost-always a serious blow to your ability to contribute to the game, I would strongly recommend any DM to allow both RHD and LA to count towards IL.

Comment: I found others sources corroborating your answer (it took me a while to find the correct wording for the issue, namely Equivalent Class Level and Level Adjustement). Here they are : http://www.minmaxboards.com/index.php?topic=5865.0 and http://www.giantitp.com/forums/showthread.php?234619-initiator-level

Thank you! 

(on an unrelated matter, the wonderful bard 4/crusader 1 you help me bring to life met his tragic and early dismiss when a pyro-hydra turn all his 5 heads toward him and unleash a unholy fire on him, RIP).